# How to get max value with some case in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table data like that:

Job Type    Job Name  Task No   Yes_NO
A ----------- X---------- 1-------- N
A ----------- X---------- 2-------- N
A ----------- X---------- 3-------- Y
A ----------- X---------- 4-------- Y
A ----------- X---------- 5-------- N
B ----------- Z---------- 1-------- N
B ----------- Z---------- 2-------- N
B ----------- Z---------- 3-------- N

The desired result should be:

Job Type    Job Name  Task No   Yes_NO

A ------------ X---------- 4--------- Y
B ------------ Z---------- 3 -------- N

But i cant successful get these lines

Case: 
get maximum task_no  for each Job Type and Job Name if Yes_NO value is 'Y'
and
if Yes_NO value is not 'Y'
get maximum task no for each Job Type and Job Name

I try something like that:

```
Select Job_Type,Job_Name,Yes_NO,max(Task No)
From Table
where  Yes_NO='Y'
Group By  Job_Type,Job_Name,Yes_NO
UNION
Select Job_Type,Job_Name,Yes_NO,max(Task No)
From Table
where  not exists(Select 1
From Table
where  Yes_NO='Y')
Group By  Job_Type,Job_Name,Yes_NO
```

Where is my fault or is there an easier way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Job_Type,Job_Name,Yes_NO,max(Task No)
From Table
where  Yes_NO='Y'
Group By  Job_Type,Job_Name,Yes_NO
UNION
Select t1.Job_Type,t1.Job_Name,t1.Yes_NO,max(t1.Task No)
From Table t1
  Left Join (select distinct Job_Type,Job_Name
             from Table where Yes_NO = 'Y'
            ) t2
    on t2.Job_Type = t1.Job_Type
    and t2.Job_Name = t1.Job_Name
Where t2.Job_Type is null
Group By  t1.Job_Type,t1.Job_Name,t1.Yes_NO
```

Comment: Hi Ron, Job_type value  is not null.Problem is I cant get maximum task_no for YES_NO value is 'N'

Comment: What the `Where t2.Job_Type is null` line does is filter out all Job_Type and Job_Name records where there exists one record `Where Yes_NO = 'Y'`. Here is a SQL Fiddle showing the results with your dataset: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98c395/4

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using FIRST/LAST aggregate functions or ROW_NUMBER analytic function.

```
select job_type, max(job_name), 
       max(task_no) keep (
         dense_rank first order by
         case when yes_no = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end,
         task_no desc
         ),
        max(yes_no) keep (
         dense_rank first order by
         case when yes_no = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end
         )
from t_table
group by job_type;

select job_type, job_name, task_no, yes_no
from (
  select job_type, job_name, task_no, yes_no,
  row_number() over (partition by job_type
                     order by case when yes_no = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end,
                     task_no desc
                     ) r
  from t_table
  )
where r = 1;
```

Result:

```
| JOB_TYPE | JOB_NAME | TASK_NO | YES_NO |
|----------|----------|---------|--------|
|        A |        X |       4 |      Y |
|        B |        Z |       3 |      N |
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6b67/6).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that worked for me in SQL Fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa5b7/6

```
select a."Job Type", a."Job Name", max("Task No") as Task_No, b.Yes_No
from maxvalueexample a
inner join (select "Job Type", "Job Name", max("Yes_NO") as Yes_No
             from maxvalueexample
              group by "Job Type", "Job Name")b
        on b."Job Type" = a."Job Type"
        and b."Job Name" = a."Job Name"
        and b.Yes_No = a."Yes_NO"
group by a."Job Type", a."Job Name", b.Yes_No
```